# How to get date and time stamp in format dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss format in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, line

Can any one please provide me a solution as to:
a. how i create a variable in windows CMD line  and store the date and time in dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss format
b. Also Please let me know how to find difference between two datetime's of the above format in windows command line

Comment: When your script should run on other computers too, be sure to use a method independent of locale settings. The `%date%` variable isn't reliable at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways, but a python Programmer I would write a short script, so that I can fit the output to my use case.

`import time
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Then you just need to execute the python script.

Under **Windows**:

`c:\path\to\python3.exe script_name.py`

and then it should return your desired timestamp.

The other option is, to create a date-time variable.

`set datetime1=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~-4% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%`

this is callable with:

`echo %datetime`

**Output**:
`01-03-2020 15:00:14`